# Door bell solenoid under alternating current

Tags: ac, solenoid

In my house, I have a set of door bells, fed by a transformer without a bridge rectifier.

Each of them basically consists of a solenoid with a spring loaded core, so when the circuit is closed, the coil magnetizes and the core is forced to hit one of the 'gong plates', and when the circuit is then opened, the magnetic field collapses and the core is then forced by power of the spring to return to its original position, but overshooting, thus hitting the opposite 'gong plate'.

Long story short, as far as I know, forcing current through a coil results in a magnetic field of opposite direction. But what I can not figure out is, how this could work with alternating current. At best, the core should wiggle around some with the frequency of the voltage.

How does it work? Is it some sorcery in the way the coil is wound? What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Even if it is AC you'll still have continuous current passing through the coil, which should be all that matters. Coils don't have polarity. All it needs is some margins so that the voltage won't drop below what's necessary to create a sufficient magnetic field to pull the mechanical parts. Likely no sorcery involved, though I can't say I've dissected a doorbell before, so I'll pass from posting this as an answer.

Comment: But shouldn't the direction of the current in the coil alternate with 60 Hz, and likewise the direction of the magnetic field that attracts the mechanical part? Or rather, what I want to say, it should just sit still, because it is forced in either direction 60 times a second.

Comment: Does the door bell emit just one "ding" or does it continually ring whilst the button is pressed? Or is it a *ding* on the press and a *dong* on the release? From your description it *sounds* like the latter (ding/dong), but it isn't totally clear.

Comment: It is the latter. Beyond the solenoid it is completely mechanical. The coil gets energized while the bell button is pressed, that makes the pin in the center of the coil move and hit a first metal plate, making ding. On release of the button it returns by force of the spring and hits a second metal plate, making dong.

Comment: @winny Is it agreeable to make a clarifying edit on top of a question while leaving the original question intact below?

Comment: The missing capital I in the beginning of the sentence? See the Tour at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour for who can edit and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic circuit is an electromagnet with a moving piece made of something like iron.  As we all know, a piece of iron/steel is attracted by both the North and South poles of a magnet.

You are quite correct: when one phase of the AC energises the coil, we get a North magnetism attracting the moving piece, this pulls the striker to hit chime 1.  During the momentary phase transition, there is no magnetism, but there isn't enough time for the striker to move. When the other phase energises the coil, we get South magnetism attracting the iron, thus holding towards chime 1.

When the AC is disconnected, the magnetism is removed, and the striker moves back.  If it's on a slight spring, it will overshoot, and hit chime 2.

The "rectification" you are looking for is in the behaviour of some magnetic materials: which is to be attracted by both N and S, and repel neither.  The pull of the magnet, as an attractive force, in newtons, is essentially a full-wave "rectified" signal of the AC input, as a voltage.  (More or less: obviously magnetism is non-linear on distance and so on.)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just happen to have one of my doorbells taken apart for repair.  Each solenoid has a spring-loaded plunger.  The resting position of the spring has the plunger mostly outside of the coil.  On each end of the plunger is a narrow rod with a rubber tip.  When AC is applied, the plunger is pulled in against the spring.  The plunger is not magnetized, so it pulls in no matter which current half-cycle is going through the coil.  The plunger over-travels, and one tip hits the ding tone bar.  Then, because the coi is energized by AC, the plunger recedes to its "on" position, centered in the coil, and sits there quivering as long as the coil is energized.  At this point the spring is compressed.

When the energizing current is removed. the spring pushes the plunger out of the coil.  It over-travels in the other direction and the other tip hits the dong tone bar.  Then the spring pulls it back to its resting "off" position.  The spring is uncompressed, the plunger is outside of the coil, and the system sits waiting for the next current pulse.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter the direction of the magnetic field, it will always displace the solenoid core in the same direction, in the same way that both north and south poles of a magnet always *attract* a lump of iron, precisely because the core is just a lump of iron.

If the core were itself a strong magnet, with a north and south pole, the story would be different. Then the direction of current would very much determine the direction that the core is displaced.

With AC, it may be true that the magnetic field created by the coil is oscillating between one direction and the other, but in either direction the core experiences a force in the same direction, because it has no permanent magnetisation of its own.

On average, when current, AC *or* DC, is flowing, the core experiences a net force always in the same direction.